Spring Rest controller returns 302 (found) for POST request but nothing happens
I'm a beginner with backend development and with Spring Boot, currently working on a project to better familiarize myself with the basics. I'm writing a simple UI for user authentication and registration, and I save the credentials in a MySQL database.
In the registration page (which consists of email, username, password), when I click "Register" (and thus submit the form), I'm redirected back to my login page (as expected), but nothing else happens. I'm getting 302 which I can see in Chrome's dev tools. Nothing happens in my database, and when I place a breakpoint in the POST request's method, it doesn't stop there, as if I'm not really invoking it as I'm expecting to.
I have a RegisterController class to create a ModelAttribute and return the relevant HTML:
@Controller
public class RegisterController {
    @GetMapping("/register")
    public String showRegisterPage(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("user", new User());
        return "register";
    }
}

I have an HTML page to create the form, populate the attributes, and submit the form to the POST request endpoint (/users/save). Here's the relevant part:
<div class="container">
    <p>Register a new user</p>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/users/save}" th:object="${user}" method="POST">
        <input type="email" th:field="*{email}" placeholder="Email">
        <input type="text" th:field="*{username}" placeholder="Username">
        <input type="password" th:field="*{hashedPassword}" placeholder="Password">
        <button type="submit">Register</button>
    </form>
    <br>
    <a th:href="@{/login}">Back to login page</a>
</div>

And finally, I have a UserRestController class to handle the POST API request:
@RestController("/users")
public class UserRestController {

    private final UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public UserRestController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/save")
    public String saveUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user){
        userService.save(user);
        return "redirect:/login";
    }

}

I tried consulting with Copilot, and learned that by default, Spring Security might block POST requests to prevent CSRF attacks. I then tried disabling csrf in my security configuration class with http.csrf().disable(), but that is deprecated. I also tried including a CSRF token in my form, by adding another input to it:
<input type="hidden" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}" th:value="${_csrf.token}"/>

But this didn't work either.
I also tried using @RequestBody in the POST request's method instead of @ModelAttribute:
@PostMapping("/save")
public String saveUser(@RequestBody User user)

But this failed as well.
It may be obvious, but I also tried placing a breakpoint in the POST request's method. The IDE didn't stop at all, as if there wasn't a breakpoint. I'm not sure how to approach this issue.

The reason that your api doesn't work is routing, you should declare the correct routing in a @RequestMapping annotation rather than in @RestController
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path="/users")
public class UserRestController {}

While this will work for you, I think another thing that might be redundant is the @ModelAttribute("user"), you can omit it and it will still work for you
@PostMapping("/save")
public String saveUser(User user){
    userService.save(user);
    return "redirect:/login";
}

Start with this tutorial https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest

Thank you, but it didn't work. I'll check the link you suggested.

Please provide more details about the error you get in the console
